# Get Items with smallest vote count including 0 in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project where I need to get the 2 items with the least amount of votes where I have 2 tables an item table and a votes table with a forgienkey of ItemId.

I have this query:

```
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT "ItemId" AS id, 
count("ItemId") AS total
FROM "Votes" 
WHERE "ItemId" IN (
        SELECT id FROM "Items" 
        WHERE date("Items"."createdAt") = date('2015-05-26 18:30:00.565+00')
        AND "Items"."region" = 'west'
        )
GROUP BY "ItemId" ORDER BY total LIMIT 2
) x;
```

Which in some respects is fine but it doesn't include the Items with the count being null or 0. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks. Please let me know if you need more info.

Postgresql: 9.4

Comment: Your schema and at least some sample data may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
SELECT id,
coalesce((SELECT count(*) FROM "Votes" WHERE "ItemId" = "Items".id), 0) as total
FROM "Items"
WHERE date("Items"."createdAt") = date('2015-05-26 18:30:00.565+00')
AND "Items"."region" = 'west'
ORDER BY total LIMIT 2
```

Comment: This does not address the NULL\0 issue. Items without votes will not be shown.

Comment: oops, forgot to remove group by. added coalesce, but it would work without it too.

Answer (score 1):

If an item has not been voted for, then the "Votes" table will not return anything for it and therefore the main query does not display the item at all.

You need to select from "Items" and then `LEFT JOIN` to "Votes" grouped by "ItemId" and the count of votes for it. Like this, all the items will be considered, also those for which no votes have been cast. Use the `coalesce()` function to convert `NULL`s to `0`:

```
SELECT "Items".id, coalesce(x.total, 0) AS cnt
FROM "Items"
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT "ItemId" AS id, count("ItemId") AS total
  FROM "Votes"
  GROUP BY "ItemId") x USING (id)
WHERE date("Items"."createdAt") = '2015-05-26'::date
  AND "Items"."region" = 'west'
ORDER BY cnt
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Patrick, I am getting an error: 'subquery in FROM  must have alias LINE 3: LEFT JOIN ('

Comment: Alias comes before the `USING` clause. Answer corrected.

Comment: This worked great. So did alexius answer. I feel like Alexius must be fast since there is no left join.